# Подъем inputField над клавиатурой

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть inputField. Мне нужно, чтобы при нажатии на него в телефоне он поднимался на уровень клавиатуры как в Телеграме или Вайбере. Спасибо!

Comment: **Ok Google:** `unity3d get keyboard height`... [TouchScreenKeyboard.area](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TouchScreenKeyboard-area.html) и вообще в статье [Mobile Keyboard](https://docs.unity3d.com/560/Documentation/Manual/MobileKeyboard.html) всё что нужно знать на эту тему... на всё, про всё, меньше минуты! Даже просто написав `unity3d keyboard` статья будет на первом месте! Мне интересно, что ты гуглил, что не смог ничего найти?

Comment: @Yaroslav нет ничего плохого в том, чтобы найденную информацию оформить ответом с примерами, если нет существущего ответа. В этом смысл StackOverflow - ответы на популярные вопросы прямо здесь.

Comment: @aepot, был бы смысл, но это ответ - ссылка, причём не куда-то там, а прям на документацию по теме. А уж если зная размер клавиатуры на экране и как получать калбеки событий клавиатуры, он не в состоянии написать лейаут, это уже другой вопрос, отвечать на который, не видя его попыток это сделать самостоятельно, мне не хочется, потому что: учи язык. Ты сам много раз видел как я писал целые валыны с примерами, но там было видно что человек старается и заинтересован.

Comment: @aepot, что касается `смысл StackOverflow - ответы на популярные вопросы`, самое популярное на `so` с тегом `unity3d`, это не `не умею писать код`, потому что не знают языка... тут мы бессильны и человек может помочь себе только сам. Это не плохо, не хорошо, это как есть, просто нужно отделять суп от мух.